# Why does my page reloads when I delete or upload something from or to the DOM/API ? I am using the preventDefault(); already

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, reload

Edit : better visibility of js code, removal of useless elements, added some html. Thanks for your feedback!

Good day everyone.

So I'm getting my "works" from an API ( http.../api/works ). I have all the works displayed on my main page using fetch method get, but also on a modal that opens up when I click a "modify" button. My modal appears with all the images and a "delete" button on each image so I can delete them from the API/DOM. My problem is that when I click that button :
1: the page reloads ( I do not wish for that to happen )
2: the image is deleted from the main page and the modal and also the API. ( which is what I wish for ).

This is the js code I use :

```
// Delete image from API when button is clicked
    deleteBtn.addEventListener("click", async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      await fetchData(`http://localhost:5678/api/works/${article.id}`, {
        method: "DELETE",
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      });
      img.remove();
      // Delete Image from the main page using the id
      const mainImg = document.querySelector(`[data-id="${article.id}"]`);
      if (mainImg) {
        mainImg.parentNode.remove();
      }
    });
```

The images are generated in a div on the html side like so :

```
<div class="modalContentBody"></div>
```

I generate the images in the modal using this fetch :

```
showModal.addEventListener("click", async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();

  const token = localStorage.getItem("token");

  const articles = await fetchData("http://localhost:5678/api/works", {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
  });
  const modalContentImg = 
  document.querySelector(".modalContentBody");modalContentImg.innerHTML = "";
  
  articles.forEach((article, index) => {etc......}
```

I open up the modal using a simple  :

```
<a class="hidden" id="showModal"><i class="fa-regular fa-pen-to-square"></i>modify</a>
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]. You've provided a *lot* of JS but not enough code to actually reproduce the problem. Add some skeleton HTML. Remove JS to reduce the problem to its code (probably the `showModal` click listener can be reduced down to just generating a single delete button). Use hardcoded data instead of Ajax. Use the stack snippets feature of the question editor to make it a live demo.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

Comment: `const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button"); deleteBtn.type="button";`

Comment: What element is `deleteBtn` referring to? If it is a HTMLButtonElement, make sure that it is not nested in a form or has `type="button"` set to it. You might want to prevent form submission if it is nested inside a form element.

Comment: I create the delete button inside the articles.forEach((article, index) => {etc......} like this : 
const deleteBtn = document.createElement("button");
deleteBtn.type="button";
deleteBtn.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash-can"></i>';
deleteBtn.classList.add("deleteImage");

Comment: Please don't add code in the comments. [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75721429/edit) to provide more code/information

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem :

I had a main folder with a folder backend and another frontend, the problem was coming from VSCodes live server. I opened ONLY the frontend folder in VSCode and the problem was solved.
I think having the backend folder in VSCode was causing the website to refresh everytime I was accessing the backend folder. All is good, thank you all!